# Replace current string setup to gather string items from xml?

Tags: java, android

```
String [] country = new String[]......
```

to instead gather items from xml.

```
String[] imgManager = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.banner);
```

Replace hardcoded String code for a more programmatically one.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String[] country = new String[] {
        "micromax",
        "samsung",
        "nokia",
        "xolo",
        "lenovo",
        "sony",
        "htc",
        "lg",
        "lava",
        "ericsson"
};
public boolean[] status = {
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        status = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
    }
    ListView lvCountries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListView lview = (ListView) lv;

            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lview.getAdapter();

            HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);
            RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;
            ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(1);
            String strStatus = "";
            if(tgl.isChecked()){
                tgl.setChecked(false);
                strStatus = "Off";
                status[position]=false;
            }else{
                tgl.setChecked(true);
                strStatus = "On";
                status[position]=true;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("txt") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    lvCountries.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        hm.put("txt", country[i]);
        hm.put("stat",status[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] from = {"txt","stat" };
    int[] to = { R.id.tv_item, R.id.tgl_status};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

    lvCountries.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried creating `R.array.banner`? What problems have you had doing so? Can you share that part of the XML?

Comment: That is all the code to it, just call <resources><string name="something"><item>... and the ListView on activity_main

Comment: You should use a `string-array`. Please see [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Comment: I actually tested the String[] imgManager = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.banner); but it crashes.

Comment: Right, because you have to move `getResources()` into `onCreate`, otherwise the context is null and the app crashes.

Comment: Ok I found my error. Actually it was a very fundamental C oriented error with the for loop that iterates the array extraction. The limit is hardcoded and I need to set it up to the length of the string array.

Comment: But thanks for troubleshooting the code with me. It was not making sense, since my approach was correct.